# What kind of signal is the signum function? A power signal or an energy signal?

Tags: telecommunication, power, energy, signal, systems-engineering

I'm studying "signals and systems". We can indentify two kinds of signals: power signal and energy signal.

The definitions are:

Energy of a time-continous signal
$$ E_x = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{|x(t)|}^2dt $$

Power of a time-continous signal
$$ P_x = \lim_{Z\rightarrow+\infty}{\frac{1}{2Z}\int_{-Z}^{+Z}{|x(t)|}^2dt}$$

An energy signal satisfies $0<E_x<+\infty$ and $P_x=0$.

A power signal satisfies $0<P_x<+\infty$ and $E_x = +\infty$.

Now, if we have a signum function

$$sgn(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & if\;t \ge 0 \\ 
-1 & if\;t < 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

and we calculate the formulas, then we obtain:

$$P_x = 0 \;\; E_x=0 $$

My question is, as the title said: the signum function which kind of signal is?

Comment: signum is hardly time continuous. (massive jump at t = 0)

Comment: Also the vertical bars indicate absolute amplitude which is a constant 1 which makes $E_{sgn} = +\infty$ and $P_{sgn} = 1$

Comment: Correct! I forgot the absolute value! Thank you for answering anyway to my stupid question! I will pay more attention next time.

Comment: @ratchetfreak That function **is time continuous**. That means there are no discontinuities **in time**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point is that signum is not continuous with the jump at $t=0$.

Second because of the absolute value in the integral it has the same $E$ and $P$ as a constant signal $1$.

This means that $E_{sgn}=+\infty$ and $P_{sgn}=1$

Comment: No one said that the function is continuous. It was claimed that the signal is **time continuous**, which it is. If you change that, I would upvote since it is otherwise a correct answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_signal